# Get data range in Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm able to get the data range of a sheet using the following function in [app script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getDataRange()):

```
function myFunction() {
  var newSheet = 
  SpreadsheetApp.openById('spreadsheetId');
  var sheet = newSheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  Logger.log(sheet.getDataRange().getA1Notation());
}
```

This returns the range: A1:B3

Is there any way to get the same thing using Google spreadsheet REST API?

Comment: Was my answer useful for you? If you have issues for my answer yet, feel free to tell me. Such information helps me to study. Also I think that it helps other users to know the situation as an information.

Answer (score 1):

When Sheets API is used, the grid range can be retrieved. But unfortunately, I couldn't find the API for retrieving data range. So I proposed this workaround. [How to get a data range of the Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48917258/how-to-get-a-data-range-of-the-sheet/48922538#48922538)

- In this answer, the data range is retrieved by Web Apps.

  - In this case, the access token is required to be used. But if you don't need to use it, please set as follows for deploying Web Apps.

    - For "Execute the app as:", set "Me".
    - For "Who has access to the app:", set "Anyone, even anonymous".

If this is also useful for your situation, I'm glad. If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks Tanaike for the quick response. But in my case, I can not ask every user to deploy this web app before using my application.

Comment: @keetz I'm sorry for the inconvenience. When many users uses, this method is not suitable. In that case, I think that as [oshliaer says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48917258/how-to-get-a-data-range-of-the-sheet/48922538#48922538), for height and width for data range, length of ``GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/values/Sheet1?majorDimension=ROWS`` and ``GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/values/Sheet1?majorDimension=COLUMNS`` can be used, respectively. I should have asked you about the situation you use at first. I'm sorry.

Comment: That's fine. Thanks for the response. This workaround makes sense.