# Java Google Sheets API v4 : How to get actual row and coloumn count

Tags: java, google-sheets

sheet.getProperties().getGridProperties().getRowCount() is returning total row from sheet not the actual row and 
sheet.getProperties().getGridProperties().getColumnCount() is returning total column from sheet not the actual coloumn.

For example if I have entered data in 20 rows with 5 columns. Then i want row count as 20 and column count as 5.  But getting row count 1000 as by default in sheet 1000 row will be there and same as column which is 26.

Comment: Is this information useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48917258/how-to-get-a-data-range-of-the-sheet/48922538#48922538

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  But it will not work in my case. I am using the API in pure Java application for batch process.

Comment: I'm really sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: @BhupenderJangra did you find any solution for this?