# How to get range of google spread sheet dynamically

Tags: java, google-sheets-api

I have a google spreadsheet and I have to print all the data of each cell.
I have written a code that is getting the data but for that, I have to define the value of **"range"**. I want the range to be dynamical i.e whatever the range of the google spreadsheet.

```
public static void readSampleSpreadsheet() throws IOException {
    // Build a new authorized API client service.
    Sheets service = getSheetsService();
    String spreadsheetId = "1gfLQTGWejFeZmp_HpTVP84ykKkKZbAE";

    String range = "A1:AZ70";

    ValueRange response = service.spreadsheets().values()

            .get(spreadsheetId, range)
            .execute();


    List<List<Object>> values = response.getValues();
    System.out.println("this is the values  " + values);
    if (values == null || values.size() == 0) {
        System.out.println("No data found.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Name, Major");
        for (List row : values) {
            // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
            System.out.println(row);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### The Sheets API does not provide such a functionality

Instead, you can use Apps Script which features the method [sheet.getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange).

You can embed the Apps Script code into you java code with the [Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api) which allows you to [execute Apps Script functions remotely](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute).

Alternatively, you can deploy the Apps Script code as a [WebApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) and incorporate its return values into your code with the deployment URL, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48922538/11599789) for a sample.